# using price deflator in monteray series over different years

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I have different series from banks balance sheets in monetary terms covering various years. I think is best to use a price deflator to control for inflation. I'm attaching two graphs the before and after of applying the deflactor to the data. For every data in the series I'm applying the following formula: row value from the balance sheet *( deflator -from base year- /  deflator -from year of the row data). Both deflators are from the world bank. [image][image]

Is it correct to do what I just mentioned?